# Guarantee anonymity to users

Tags: security

I have programmed a system for internal behavior reporting for my company's intranet. I should not have access to its data (not being part of the controlling committee, but I have.

I've locked my account away from the data, but I could unlock it. I could store the data in an encrypted format, but, even if chosen by someone else, I should store the salt somewhere and hence read it -> decrypt the data.

From a *theoretical* point of view (I'm not talking about a particular system or framework or utility), how can I **not** have access to the data stored in a system I have complete control of?

Comment: This might be better asked on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you could just set passwords such that only one user has access to the database, then allow someone else to set that password.  It would make maintenance a bit more tricky, but then again a database shouldn't need a ton of maintenance on a tool like this once all is said, done, and thoroughly tested.

If this is internal, it would be nothing to setup a dedicated, physically secure WAMP or similar machine that's solely dedicated to this purpose.  Have someone else tweak root passwords and store them with the "committee" and you're off the hook, in theory.

I suppose if one was to be completely paranoid, one could build a web service to isolate the database completely on a separate network from the reporting functionality.  In theory, you could setup the web service on a remote machine that your access is removed from, then use the front-end to collect data and pass it to the webservice.  From there, it's completely out of your hands, with no "data out" webservice to retrieve data.

Security is always a messy subject.  I've worked in banking, ecommerce, and sports (drug testing) environments where I'm knee-deep in confidential data and it is more than just a bit scary.  At some point, you just have to do the best you can do, document your safeguards, be "read in" on proper protocol and required background checks, do thorough testing with independent testers, and then just maintain complete transparency.  In the IT world we have access to a ridiculous amount of information, and that's never going to go away.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is [Mandatory Access Control](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.64.8693&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The kind of access control most computer user are familir with is [Discressionary Access Control](http://web.mit.edu/6.857/OldStuff/Fall96/lectures/lecture24.ps.gz). In DAC (Discressionary Access Control) everything on the computer is owned by a user. Users can grant access of an object (file, service, peripheral, memory, etc) to another user. Users can even transfer ownership of an object to another user. In MAC (Manditory Access Control) at least some objects are not owned by any user. The rules governing how users can access or interact with these objects are fixed and unchangable by any user.

In your example the data generated by the reporting system should be protected by Manditory Access Control, but the reporting system configuration may be owned by you. So you can control how the system behaves but not have access to the data it generates.

Microsoft began implementing MAC with Windows Vista. In Vista it was called Mandatory Integrity Control (MIC).

Linux can implement MAC with SELinux or AppArmor.

Mac OS X uses an implementation of the TrustedBSD MAC.

So, why isn't MAC used more often?
I takes effort. It is not easy to set up MAC, and it is hard to change once it is set up. It can be complicated. Most systems and services are built on the DAC model. Turning on MAC often makes services stop working.